# Statement on different SQL Server with different languages

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I insert with a SQL statement into a table two dates, but I use it on different machines with different SQL Server and set language. Sometimes '2017-01-04 00:00:00' is April 01, 2017 sometimes it is January 04, 2017. I want April 01.

```
INSERT INTO [table] ([id], [value], [datefrom], [dateto])
    SELECT
        NEWID(), 3.5, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', '2027-01-05 00:00:00'
    FROM 
        [settings]
```

Can I use just use `SET LANGUAGE german;` at the beginning of the script and this setting is only temporary for the statement and does not change the language permanently? Or is this not a good way to go? See used statement below. Thanks in advance.

```
SET LANGUAGE german;

INSERT INTO [table]([id], [value], [datefrom], [dateto])
    SELECT
        NEWID(), 3.5, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', '2027-01-05 00:00:00'
    FROM 
        [settings]
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39439/110455

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to support multiple language settings, it's best to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601** format for SQL Server dates-as-string-literals.

If you need to use `DATETIME` (which should be phased out as of SQL Server 2008 - use `DATE` if you need only date, `DATETIME2(n)` if you need both dates & time), use one of two possible formats:

```
YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS        // **NO** dashes for the date portion!
```

or

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS      // delimiter "T" between date and time parts
```

Preferably, if you really only need the `DATE` (no time), use the `DATE` datatype and then use this format:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

This is guaranteed to work **always** and without having to switch around date and language settings just to make your `INSERT` statements work ....

Thus `20170401` will **always** be interpreted as "April 1, 2017"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a language neutral (ODBC) literal, `{d 'YYYYMMDD'}` for date and `{ts'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]'}` for datetime.

So

```
{ts '2017-04-01 00:00:00'}
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

The command
    SET LANGUAGE
Works on the session level, so it would solve your problem
see the [MDSN Article on the command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174398.aspx) for specifics